# using watchman only on specific project

Tags: ember.js, watchman

I am running 2 ember applications on my computer.

On one of them I want watchman to run (to solve `EMFILE: too many open files, watch`), 
on the other project I do not want it to run - since it causes an error (`TypeError: Invalid Version: 2022.06.27.00`)

Is there a way to configure watchman to run/ not run on specific projects?

Comment: seems like the watchman error can be fixed by installing a more up to date version? 

This error is reported here, and is related to brew: https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/915

Comment: if I run `brew install watchman` doesn't it install the latest version? that's what I did a few days ago and i still got the error